# how can i show the pdf hyper link data in popover in iPad apps?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf, uidocument, qlpreviewcontroller

i have worked pdf file reader in iPad apps using QLPreviewcontroller but i need to show the  inside of pdf hyper link show on popover in iPad any one can help out.

```
 documentPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_file" ofType:@"pdf"];
        fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentPath];
        //fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLUIDocumentInteractionControllerPDF];

}
//creating the object of the QLPreviewController
QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

//settnig the datasource property to self
previewController.dataSource = self;

//pusing the QLPreviewController to the navigation stack
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
//remove the right bar print button
[previewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
[previewController release];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is not impossible, but is extremely complicated and likely will take thousands of lines of code. Quartz has all the functions you'll need to do what your asking, but it will be a major undertaking into poorly documented structures.

This would be much more possible to accomplish using an external library. I've done it before with [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com) as well as [Foxit Embedded SDK](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/embedded/), but neither is cheap. If your code is GPL licensed, you could consider [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com), but it's probably not helpful for commercial software.